# Rails - Heroku error, nothing in logs, works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've just made some minor modifications to my rails app and now one route works perfectly **locally**, but raises an error on **Heroku**.

This is a simple route that directs to '`new`' of my `controller`.

Everything works fine locally, but in prod: It raise the Heroku error

> We're sorry, but something went wrong

There is nothing in the logs, I've also put some `Rails.logger.warn` in the method, but **nothing appears**.

1. How is it possible to get a specific error in production Heroku but not in local?
2. Can I get the same process in local to see the error and fix it?

Comment: Did you run the app locally in development or production? If development, try to run it in production and see if you encounter any errors.

Comment: Nothing in logs even in production mode.
But I found the anwser, I've Just reset the DB

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely try to reproduce the issue locally by fetching the data to local database.

First make sure your current branch (most likely master) is same as heroku `master` where the app is deployed.

Then pull the database to local and try to re do the same steps. Follow commands will help you capture latest snapshot and store the database to local.

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app sushi
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app sushi`
rake db:drop db:create
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner [-U user_name] -d database_name latest.dump
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Answer (score 1):

Did you migrate the database in Heroku? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: yes, I've done this juste after getting the error, just in case. But I didn't change the DB in days